# Not all categories are being shown in bar highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create one highchart with lots of data. Below is the code i have written to create it. But somehow on the X-Axis not all the categories are being shown. Attached is the Fiddle

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/78yesztL/18/)

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('containerSDRangeDOJ', {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      marginLeft: 150,
      marginBotton: 50
    },
    legend: {
      y: -20
    },
    title: {
      text: "Top Source-Destination",
      align: "center"
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Some link to download this data'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      min: 1,
      max: 15,
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
      },
      tickLength: 1,

    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: {
        text: 'Oops Count',
        align: 'middle'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false

    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Count',
      data: [
        ["Bangalore to Chennai", 40],
        ["Bangalore to Madurai", 55],
        ["Bangalore to Chennai", 40],
        ["Bangalore to Chennai", 40],
        ["Bangalore to Chennai", 40]
      ]
    }]
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things going on that are affecting this.

1) You are setting the x axis `min` to `1`. The first category starts at `0`, so you are telling the chart to skip it.

2) Your 3rd, 4th, and 5th data points are all listed as the same category, so it is associating them all with the same category on the axis.  It won't repeat categories - they need to be unique if you are specifying them in the data point like that.

For example:

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    min: 0,
    max: 14
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Count',
      data: [
        ["Bangalore to Chennai", 40],
        ["Bangalore to Madurai", 55],
        ["Bangalore to Chennai2", 40],
        ["Bangalore to Chennai3", 40],
        ["Bangalore to Chennai4", 40]
      ]
    }]
```

Updated fiddle with x axis min set to 0, and category names edited:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/78yesztL/20/

Answer (score 0):

Point which are mentioned by @jlbriggs are the problems

I added a hack for the second point (unique name) to show correct labels in xAxis

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/hwerdks2/3/)

Try using chart load events to check each names in data. If current name is matching to previous then add a space to it (*name length changes from the previous one and it becomes a different name but looks the same*) and form new array and update the chart series with this array.

```
chart: {
type: 'bar',
  marginLeft: 150,
  marginBotton: 50,
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var series_data = this.series[0].data; 
      var current_item;
      var spaces=""
      var datas=[]
      for (var i = 0; i < series_data.length; i++) {
            current_item=series_data[i].name
            if(current_item==series_data[i].name){
          spaces+=" ";
                var sName=series_data[i].name+spaces
              datas.push([sName,series_data[i].y])
          }else{
          spaces=""

          datas.push([series_data[i].name,series_data[i].y])
          }

      }
                this.update({
        series: {
          data: datas
        },
      });

    }
  }
},
```

personally I think you should use this example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/hwerdks2/2/)